# Espresso test cannot be recorded occured when Record Robo script clicked

Tags: android, robotframework, android-espresso, android-espresso-recorder

I have some problem to record robo script for Firebase Test lab.
My android project is not making by Compose projects but it occured error
"Espresso test cannot be recorded _ Espresso Testing Framework does not support Compose projects"
when I pressing button "Record Robo Script".

Is there something I'm missing out on?
Attach project components that may be problematic

**This is build.gradle(:app)**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ...hide...
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 23
        versionName "1.0.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        dev {
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11'
    }

    viewBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }

}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    // Firebase
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.2.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx'

    // Lottie BottomNavigation
    implementation 'com.github.wwdablu:lottiebottomnav:1.2.0'

    // Network
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.6.0'

    // Material Design
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'

    // RecyclerView Selection
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0"
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.1.0"

    // Lifecycle components
    def lifecycle_version = '2.5.1'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
    kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"


    // Image Glide
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.13.2'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:4.13.2'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.13.2'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.13.2'
    implementation 'com.caverock:androidsvg-aar:1.4'


    // Chart Library
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'

    // Lottie Library
    implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:5.0.3"

    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.11.1"

    // RollingTextView
    implementation "com.github.YvesCheung.RollingText:RollingText:1.2.11"
    implementation "com.daasuu:CountAnimationTextView:0.1.2"


    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.2.1'

    // QR Scanner
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:4.3.0'

    // OTP View
    implementation 'com.github.mukeshsolanki:android-otpview-pinview:3.0.0'

    // 생체인증
    implementation "androidx.biometric:biometric:1.1.0"

    // Skeleton UI
    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.5.0'

    // 카카오 로그인
    implementation "com.kakao.sdk:v2-all:2.11.2"

    // Crashlytics SDK
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'

    // Testing Fragment
    def fragment_version = "1.5.3"
    debugImplementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:$fragment_version"

    implementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.4.0'
}
```

**This is build.gradle(:project)**

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.2'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.21' apply false

}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**This is settings.gradle**

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        jcenter()
    }
}
rootProject.name = ..hide..
include ':app'
```

I tried to find out which elements are using Jetpack Compose but there was no such element.

The detailed reason is not explained, so I don't know any more
I think it's possible to use compose from an external library.
not sure

Comment: Did you solve this?? I also had the same problem. Could it be related to the M1 MacBook?

Comment: @KimJitae Not yet. I'm using an m1 MacBook, and I'm using the Android bumblebee version.